# Google map with auto zoom and custom markers stays grey

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

Hey guys I am having a hard time getting my Google map working with an auto zoom and custom markers. In the Google chrome console I get

```
too much recursion
...(0,0);Ba(T[I],function(){return"("+this.x+", "+this.y+")"});T[I].b=function(a){r...
main.js (ligne 24)

too much recursion
...nged")}var Lf={};function If(a){return Lf[a]||(Lf[a]=a[Bb](0,1).toUpperCase()+a[...
main.js (ligne 25)
```

the main.js file is hosted by Google here http://maps.gstatic.com/intl/fr_ALL/mapfiles/api-3/10/19/main.js

I really dont understand the problem

```
<?php
print ('
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
        var map;
        var markersArray = [];
        var image = \'img/\';
        var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
        var loc;

        var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP };

        map =  new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

        ');

            $l=1; 
            foreach($carte as $value){
                if ($carte[$l][lat]&&$carte[$l][lon]){
                /*echo '
                    loc = new google.maps.LatLng("'.$carte[$l][lat].'","'.$carte[$l][lon].'");
                    bounds.extend(loc);
                    addMarker(loc, \'Event A\', "active");
                ';*/

                echo '
                    loc = new google.maps.LatLng("'.$carte[$l][lat].'","'.$carte[$l][lon].'");
                    bounds.extend(loc);
                    addMarker(loc, \''.htmlentities($carte[$l][nom], ENT_QUOTES).str_replace('<br />', '', htmlentities($carte[$l][addresse], ENT_QUOTES)).'\', "active", "'.$l.'");

                ';

                }


                $l++;
            }


        print ('

        map.fitBounds(bounds);
        map.panToBounds(bounds);    

        function addMarker(location, name, active) {          
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                map: map,
                title: name,
                status: active
            });
        }

    });

</script>');
?>
```

I made a js fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/KwayW/48/

Any help would be apreciated at this point

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two issues:

1. You are passing strings into the [google.maps.LatLng constructor](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)
2. That string representation has a comma in it rather than a decimal point

The `google.maps.LatLng` requires two numbers.

```
loc = new google.maps.LatLng("47,036084","-70,461227");
```

should be:

```
loc = new google.maps.LatLng(47.036084,-70.461227);
```

[Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGBzv/2/)

BTW - all your markers are in the same location...

Comment: [updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rGBzv/2/) since StackOverflow wouldn't let me post the answer including it.